# $a+b=21$ and $\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b} =\frac{7}{18} $. What is $ab$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$ab$ is:

A. $18$

B. $36$

C. $54$

D. $72$

E. $90$

Would like to know if there is a way other than testing out each option to get the answer.

Comment: You already have 2 good answers (you should accept one). This is not an answer, just a comment - but this problem illustrates how, given exactly two of the three commonly used means of two numbers - i.e. the arithmetic (AM), geometric (GM) and harmonic mean (HM) - you can derive the third mean.

Answer (score 4):

Well, $$\frac{7}{18}=\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}=\frac{b+a}{ab}=\frac{21}{ab}$$  and so $$ab=\frac{21(18)}{7}=54$$

Answer (score 2):

$$\begin{array}{rcl}
\dfrac1a + \dfrac1b &=& \dfrac7{18} \\
\dfrac b{ab} + \dfrac a{ab} &=& \dfrac7{18} \\
\dfrac{b+a}{ab} &=& \dfrac7{18} \\
\dfrac{a+b}{ab} &=& \dfrac7{18} \\
\dfrac{21}{ab} &=& \dfrac7{18} \\
\dfrac{ab}{21} &=& \dfrac{18}7 \\
ab &=& 54
\end{array}$$

Answer (score 1):

Just from a style point of view, I prefer to avoid fractions until the very end, so I'll just multiply both sides of the 2nd equation by $18ab$.

$$\begin{align}
\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b} &= \frac{7}{18}\\
18ab\bigg(\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}\bigg) &= 18ab\bigg(\frac{7}{18}\bigg)\\
\frac{18ab}{a}+\frac{18ab}{b} &= \frac{7\cdot18ab}{18}\\
18b+18a &=7ab\\
7ab &= 18(\color{green}{a+b)}\\
7ab &= 18\cdot \color{green}{21}\\
ab & = \frac{18\cdot 21}{7} = \frac{18\cdot 3 \cdot 7}{7} = 18\cdot 3 = 54
\end{align}$$